# Ignore points in Folium PolyLines

Tags: python-3.x, folium, polyline

I am plotting a satellite ground track using [Folium PolyLine](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html).
Among the set of points (latitudes longitudes) I am passing to my map, there are two points in that set that I do not want a line drawn between. I do not want the horizontal line drawn (see screenshot below):
[image]

Here is the code that generates the map:

```
my_map = folium.Map(location=[0,0], height=1000, width=1000, zoom_start=2, 
    min_zoom=2, max_zoom=12, max_bounds=True, no_wrap=True)
map_name = "folium_1000_1000_map.html"
#add line to my_map
folium.PolyLine(latlon_list).add_to(my_map)
```

Where **latlon_list** is a list of 2000 tuples, with each tuple holding a latitude/longitude combination `([lat0, lon0],[...],[lat1999,lon1999])`.
I do not want to start the line on the far left side of the map (it is important that I have precise representation of orbit, even if it means having the orbit starting on the right side of map, like it is on the example screenshot). How can I get rid of the horizontal line ?

Comment: Have you tried drawing two PolyLines instead of a single one?